# \usepackage{sectsty} and problems with \pagebreak

Tags: sectioning, floats, page-breaking

**UPDATE WHERE IT BREAKS DOWN... PLEASE REFER TO CODE BELOW. I ADDED ONE MORE PACKAGE and ONE DEFINITION**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage{booktabs} %%<-- added NEW NEW ENWE NEW
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}} %%%%% <--- added NEW NEW NEW NEW
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text 
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}% 
\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{1.4ex}{2pt}{-.6ex}{2pt}%
{\small \sffamily\centering\vspace{-2.65ex}\MakeUppercase}}
%\allsectionsfont{\raggedright\ulemheading{\uuline}}
\subsectionfont{\sffamily\MakeUppercase}
\vspace{-5ex}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}% dummy text
\contentsmargin{0cm}
% End of preamble ===========================
\begin{document}
\chapter{hello3}
\section{hello blinder}
\subsection{nothing}
-
\subsection{nothing}
-
\subsection{sample}
{\small
\begin{table}[H]
\caption*{{\small $\blacksquare$: Man.\\ $\square$: Woman }}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{next generation}}\\
\head{{\footnotesize byye}} & \head{{\footnotesize hello}}\\
\midrule
\hfill$\blacksquare$ &\hfill$\blacksquare$ \\\hfill$\square$ &\hfill$\square$ \\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
}
{\tiny
\begin{table}[H]
{\small
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{next generation}}\\
\head{{\footnotesize next  1}} & \head{{\footnotesize next 2}}\\
\midrule
\hfill$\blacksquare$ &\hfill$\blacksquare$\\\hfill$\square$ &\hfill$\square$\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
}
\subsection{sample2}
\centering
\textbf{sample3}
asdasdasd
\textbf{sample2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
tick label style={font=\small},
tickpos=left,
xticklabels={}, 
xtick={1,2,3,4},
ymin=0,
legend entries={zzz, yyy, xxx },
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
scaled y ticks = false,
set thousands separator={},
fixed
},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.23) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.51) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.26)  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subsection{FACILITIES}
-
\subsection{sample}
\blindtext[2]
\section{New Section}
\subsection{clown4}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{clown3}
\blindtext[4]
\subsection{clown2}
{\small
\begin{table}[H]
\caption*{{\small $\blacksquare$: Man.\\ $\square$: Woman. }}
{\small
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{next generation}}\\
\head{{\footnotesize next generation}} & \head{{\footnotesize next generation}}\\
\midrule
En\hfill$\blacksquare$ &Ena\hfill$\blacksquare$ \\Chi\hfill$\square$           
&Chiegua\hfill$\square$ \\Maics\hfill$\square$ &Macs\hfill$\square$ 
\\Science\hfill$\square$ &Lidie\hfill$\square$ \\Compuer\hfill$\square$ 
&Phs\hfill$\square$ \\Chnesor\hfill$\square$ &Chery\hfill$\square$ 
\\Hisy\hfill$\square$ &Bigy\hfill$\square$    \\Gehy\hfill$\square$ 
&Infoationan\hfill$\square$ \\Eccau\hfill$\square$ &Bess\hfill$\square$ 
\\Mic\hfill$\square$ &Accond\hfill$\square$ \\Physica\hfill$\square$ 
&Ecmics\hfill$\square$ \\VisualArts\hfill$\square$ &Chior\hfill$\square$ 
\\Ded\hfill$\square$ &Hiy\hfill$\square$ \\Hoonomics\hfill$\square$ 
&Geaphy\hfill$\square$ \\Putua\hfill$\square$ &Touros\hfill$\square$ 
\\Lie\hfill$\square$ &Viss\hfill$\square$   \\&Desppl\hfill$\square$ 
\\&Phyduca\hfill$\square$ \\&Schr\hfill$\square$ \\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
}
{\tiny
\begin{table}[H]
{\small
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule[1.5pt]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\head{2013/2014}}\\
\head{{\footnotesize S1-S3}} & \head{{\footnotesize S4-S6}}\\
\midrule
Brownie\hfill$\blacksquare$ &Brownie \hfill$\blacksquare$\\Cheap\hfill$\square$ 
&Cheap\hfill$\square$\\womanizer\hfill$\square$ &womanizer 
\hfill$\square$\\Scce\hfill$\square$ &eie\hfill$\square$\\Comr\hfill$\square$ 
&Phcs\hfill$\square$\\Cheap\hfill$\square$ &hy\hfill$\square$\\Hiy\hfill$\square$ 
&Bgy\hfill$\square$\\Gphy\hfill$\square$ &form\hfill$\square$\\Ecu\hfill$\square$ 
&Bss\hfill$\square$\\Mic\hfill$\square$ &Accand\hfill$\square$\\Pca\hfill$\square$ 
&Eccs\hfill$\square$\\Vts\hfill$\square$ &Cistor\hfill$\square$\\Ded\hfill$\square$ 
&Hory\hfill$\square$\\Hcs\hfill$\square$ &aphy\hfill$\square$\\hua\hfill$\square$ 
&Tos\hfill$\square$\\Liie\hfill$\square$   
&Vts\hfill$\square$\\&Dppl\hfill$\square$\\&Pca\hfill$\square$\\&SdAr\hfill$\square$\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
}
\subsection{Spring term}
\centering
\textbf{helloo clown}
asdasdasd
\textbf{hello baffoon}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
tick label style={font=\small},
tickpos=left,
xticklabels={}, 
xtick={1,2,3,4},
ymin=0,
legend entries={$0-4$ years, $5-9$ years, $>10$ years },
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
scaled y ticks = false,
set thousands separator={},
fixed
},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.42) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.28) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.3)  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subsection{something2}
\blindtext[3]
\subsection{something 4}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

So, I amended the generous and insightful solution in the answer below and it appears to break down as I include other information .... for instance the `\hello macro` ... I believe that was one of the reasons I used the `extraplaceins` package in my original solution.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}%    

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{1.4ex}{2pt}{-.6ex}{2pt}%
{\small \sffamily\centering\vspace{-2.65ex}\MakeUppercase}}
%\allsectionsfont{\raggedright\ulemheading{\uuline}}
\subsectionfont{\sffamily\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand\firstoftwo[2]{#1}
\newcommand\secondoftwo[2]{#2}
\newcommand\hello[9]{%
{\small \sffamily 
\firstoftwo#1\hfill\\% Address
\textbf{\Large Hello} \firstoftwo#2~~$\circ$~~%
\textbf{\Large Hello} \secondoftwo#2\\ 
\textbf{\Large Kitty} \firstoftwo#3 \hfill\\  
\textbf{\Large Pitty} \url{\firstoftwo#5}\hfill\\
\textbf{Smoothness} \firstoftwo#8~~$\circ$~~% 
\textbf{Classification} \firstoftwo#4\\
\textbf{Car Sales} \firstoftwo#9~~$\circ$~~%
\textbf{Micro Sales} \secondoftwo#5\\
\textbf{Ornamentation year} \secondoftwo#9~~$\circ$~~%
\textbf{Gesticulation cancer} \secondoftwo#7\\
\textbf{unknown parody} \secondoftwo#8~~$\circ$~~\\
\textbf{annoying} \secondoftwo#4\\ 
\textbf{as hell} \firstoftwo#6~~\textemdash~~%
\secondoftwo#6}
\begin{quoting}
\footnotesize\Fontskrivan%\calligra ... what you want
\firstoftwo#7
\end{quoting}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
\color{gray}
\offinterlineskip
\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{.2ex}\vspace{.5mm}
\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{.4ex}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-5ex}
}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello world}
\blindtext[2]
\section{Hello section title}
\hello
{{ 123123123123132123213}}%
{{123123213}{123123123}}%
{{1233213123123}}%
{{123123123}{asdasdasddasd}}%
{{asdasdasda}{asdadsad}}%
{{asdadasd}{adsadsad}}%
{{adsasdad}{asdadsasd}}
{{asdasdadasdads}}
{{asdasdadsad}{asdasdasd}}




\blindtext[2]
\subsection{some tables and figures here}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{testing}
\blindtext[2]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[%
ybar,
tick label style={font=\small},
tickpos=left,
xticklabels={}, 
xtick={1,2,3,4},
ymin=0,
legend entries={$0-4$ years, $5-9$ years, $>10$ years },
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
    scaled y ticks = false,
    set thousands separator={},
    fixed
},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.23) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.51) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.26)  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\subsection{hello}

\section{section title here}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{something}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{something else}
\blindtext[2]
\subsection{another subsection}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{here is a subsection}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
tick label style={font=\small},
tickpos=left,
xticklabels={}, 
xtick={1,2,3,4},
ymin=0,
legend entries={$0-4$ years, $5-9$ years, $>10$ years },
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
  scaled y ticks = false,
  set thousands separator={},
  fixed
},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.42) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.28) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.3)  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}







\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{aurical}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}% 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}% dummy text
\usepackage{quoting}
\quotingsetup{vskip=5pt}
\usepackage{PTSansNarrow} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\textnormal{\textbf{#1}}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[section,subsection,subsubsection]{extraplaceins}


\renewcommand\epigraphflush{flushright}
\renewcommand\epigraphsize{\normalsize}
\setlength\epigraphwidth{0.7\textwidth}






%------------------------------------------
\contentsmargin{0cm}
%------------------------------------------


\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{1.4ex}{2pt}{-.6ex}{2pt}%
{\small \sffamily\centering\vspace{-2.65ex}\MakeUppercase}}
%\allsectionsfont{\raggedright\ulemheading{\uuline}}
\subsectionfont{\sffamily\MakeUppercase}
\vspace{-5ex}




% End of preamble ===========================

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hellow world}
\section{Hello section title}
\subsection{some tables and figures here}
\subsection{testing}
\centering
\textbf{something else}
\textbf{some diagram}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
tick label style={font=\small},
tickpos=left,
xticklabels={}, 
xtick={1,2,3,4},
ymin=0,
legend entries={$0-4$ years, $5-9$ years, $>10$ years },
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
      scaled y ticks = false,
      set thousands separator={},
      fixed
},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.23) };
 \addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.51) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.26)  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\subsection{hello}
-
\section{section title here}
\subsection{something}
something
\subsection{something else}
\subsection{another subsection}
\subsection{here is a subsection}
\centering
\textbf{Some Tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
tick label style={font=\small},
tickpos=left,
xticklabels={}, 
xtick={1,2,3,4},
ymin=0,
legend entries={$0-4$ years, $5-9$ years, $>10$ years },
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
      scaled y ticks = false,
      set thousands separator={},
      fixed
},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.42) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.28) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.3)  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Update:

As Mico correctly pointed out, I did not provide the entire context to the problem.
I am using the following environment:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
```

and related hopefully relevant info follow below

```
\contentsmargin{0cm}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thepart}{20pt}{\Huge}

\titlecontents{part}[0pc]
{
\protect\addvspace{13pt}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\draw[help lines,step=.4cm,color=blue] (0,0) grid (2.4,1.2);%
\pgftext[left,x=.1cm,y=.6cm]{\Large\scshape\partname};%
\fill[fill=white,draw=blue] (1.8,.6) circle (0.4cm);%
\node at(1.8cm,.6cm) {I};%
\end{tikzpicture}\\\color{blue}\large\scshape\bfseries
\thepart}%

{}

{l}

{$\;$\titlerule$\;$\large\bfseries\thecontentspage}%



\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\sectionrule{1.4ex}{2pt}{-.6ex}{2pt}%
{\small \sffamily\centering\vspace{-2.65ex}\MakeUppercase}}
%\allsectionsfont{\raggedright\ulemheading{\uuline}}
\subsectionfont{\sffamily\MakeUppercase}
\newcommand\firstoftwo[2]{#1}
\newcommand\secondoftwo[2]{#2}
\newcommand\ContactUs[9]{%
{\small \sffamily 
\firstoftwo#1\hfill\\% 
\textbf{\Large \XXX} \firstoftwo#2~~$\circ$~~%
\textbf{\Large \YYY} \secondoftwo#2\\
\textbf{\Large \ZZZ} \firstoftwo#3 \hfill\\
}
\begin{quoting}
\footnotesize\Fontskrivan%\calligra ... 
\firstoftwo#7
\end{quoting}
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
\color{gray}
\offinterlineskip
\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{.2ex}\vspace{.5mm}
\rule[0ex]{\linewidth}{.4ex}
\end{minipage}
\vspace{-5ex}
}

\newcommand\ZZZ[6]{%
{\footnotesize\sffamily%
\textbf{ Wow:} #1\hfill%\\
\textbf{Bow:} #4 \hfill%
}}
```

## These are the ones relevant for the `\usepackage{sectsty}` package I believe.

I am using the `\usepackage{sectsty}` for nicely decorating each `\section{xxxx}`. I'd like to start a new page after each section so as to avoid floating problems. So, ideally, I'd like to have each section compile individually and independently of others. When the latex algorithm runs through and decides to placings of figures and tables, I'd like to fool it into believing that each section is on its own and nothing follows after it. How can I accomplish this ?

I thought that simply placing a `\pagebreak` or `\newpage` or even `\clearpage` will do this. Unfortunately, whenever I do this something weird happens with my content in the `\section`

command ... I obtain error messages

```
>>! Package sectsty Error: Can't use \sectionrule with \centering.

>>See the sectsty package documentation for explanation.

>>Type  H <return>  for immediate help.

>> ...
```

And the formatting that I designed for each section is lost. Is there any work around ?

Oh, yes, I run pdflatex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) Please add a MWE (minimum working example) that shows how you use the `sectsty` package to "decorate" section headers and that generates the error and warning messages you get. Incidentally, have you tried inserting the instruction `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` in the preamble? Doing so should prevent any floats from being placed *after* the start of the next section, irrespective of what you do with section header decorations.

Comment: @mico.@Mico. I did try to use `\usepackage[section]{placeins}' package. but since I am already in need to use `\usepackage[section, subsection and subsubsection]{extraplaceins}'  won't work  I am receiving compilation error msgs. `! LaTeX Error: Command \@fb@secFB already defined.'

Comment: The fact that you're already using the `placeins` package is material information you should mention up front, in the body of your posting. Please post an MWE showing what you've done so far; the information you've posted up to now simply doesn't allow a decent diagnosis of what may be going wrong.

Comment: The formatting of your question is really hard to read ... really hard.  Tidying it up would be useful.  Also a real [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) is still to be desired.

Comment: I'll put something together in a few hrs. Sorry about the unclear formatting. I am pretty new here. I'll also look at wat is required for a minimal example. cheers.

Comment: I'm afraid there are many problems with the code posted above.  Too many for me to guess how it all fits together, anyway.  However, if you want to start a new page with each section (even in a two-column format?), you could do `\usepackage{etoolbox}\pretocmd{\section}{\newpage}{}{}`.  ... However, the above code is too broken for this to work, and it may not play nice with whatever else you are doing.  Alternatively, the `\include` command always starts a new page, so you could put each section in its own file and call them like so: `\include{FirstSection}\include{SecondSection}`....

Comment: `titlesec` and `sectsty` fight with each other. Either of them can be used, but not both.

Comment: @jon, I apologize and will work on an example. I tried \include some time ago and it did not work. I'm unsure about etoolbox package. please stay tuned. I'd need ur input in abit.

Comment: @egreg, hmm .. not sure what to do here.

Comment: @allandeveryone. just provided mwe.

Comment: @egreg : how would i re-write then, to avoid problems. becasuse if i now leave out one of them, it causes problems

Comment: A few observations: the documentation to `sectsty` explicitly says: (1) `\sectionrule` does *not* work with `\centering` (so use `titlesec` instead); (2) `\sectionrule` must be the last command in a `\<section>font` command. Also `extraplaceins` is not a standard package, so it is hard to guess what it is (not) doing. Also: `\MakeUppercase` takes an argument.  Also: the line (46) `\vspace{-5ex}` can't do anything there.  Finally, this is still not quite a minimal example: most of the packages besides `sectsty` can be left out and the problem still occurs.

Answer (score 4):

There are several errors and unnecessary packages in the given code for the MWE.

I did a little pretty printing, removed calls to unneeded packages for this problem and got a running MWE.  I deleted the macro `\centering`.  See the last image for how to center it.

If I misunderstood something please copy my MWE, change it and show us your problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{geometry,xcolor,amssymb,amsmath,graphicx}% 

\usepackage{sectsty} 
\sectionfont{\sectionrule{1.4ex}{2pt}{-.6ex}{2pt}%
{\small \sffamily\centering\vspace{-2.65ex}\MakeUppercase}}
%\allsectionsfont{\raggedright\ulemheading{\uuline}}
\subsectionfont{\sffamily\MakeUppercase}
\vspace{-5ex}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}% dummy text

\contentsmargin{0cm}

% End of preamble ===========================


\begin{document}

\chapter{Hello world}
\blindtext[2]
\section{Hello section title}
\blindtext[2]
\subsection{some tables and figures here}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{testing}
\blindtext[2]
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
  \begin{axis}[%
    ybar,
    tick label style={font=\small},
    tickpos=left,
    xticklabels={}, 
    xtick={1,2,3,4},
    ymin=0,
    legend entries={$0-4$ years, $5-9$ years, $>10$ years },
    y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
        scaled y ticks = false,
        set thousands separator={},
        fixed
    },
  ]
    \addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.23) };
    \addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.51) };
    \addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.26)  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\subsection{hello}

\section{section title here}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{something}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{something else}
\blindtext[2]
\subsection{another subsection}
\blindtext[1]
\subsection{here is a subsection}
\blindtext[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=.6]
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
tick label style={font=\small},
tickpos=left,
xticklabels={}, 
xtick={1,2,3,4},
ymin=0,
legend entries={$0-4$ years, $5-9$ years, $>10$ years },
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,%
      scaled y ticks = false,
      set thousands separator={},
      fixed
},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=-.4cm, area legend] coordinates {(1,0.42) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.0cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.28) };
\addplot  +[bar shift=.4cm, area legend]coordinates {(1,0.3)  };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**Update:**

In your updated MWE you used macro `\centering` in lines 59 and 143. The resulting error message:

> ```
> ! Package sectsty Error: Can't use \sectionrule with \centering.
> ```

Comment both `\centering` with `%` and your MWE compiles.

This macro centers everything following. You can use

```
{% begin a group
 \centering  %centering starts now
 code, to be centered ...
}% ends group, ends \centering
```

to stop centering after the closing `}`.

In your case `\centering` is still workíng for `\section{New Section}` in line 87. That causes the error.

Comment: I see where this is heading. I experimented with a more fully fledged version where it breaks down. Please take a look ... assuming the same packages I included : please see above since it does not fit here.

Comment: hmm not sure how to improve this. and yes, one of the arguement will be a URL .... I have just now only inputted numbers .... how to I remedy the situation and make it work. Also, in first  place u will alsway get a mini graphics included. i.e. \hello{{\includegraphics[scale=.4]{...} some text}}{{......}....}.

Comment: please see the new code which makes use of ur MWR and adds one package and one new command ... these cause the `\sectionsty` compilation problem.

Comment: can you please take another look at this ?

Comment: you are genius! but there's the annyoing error of the section liner ... it breaks still. just compile it and realize that the \section{....} does not work anymore properly. Why is this ?

Comment: that is to say, even if we salvage the \centering problem (which, thanks to your insight, we have). The major issue turns into ... how do we maintain a proper formatting of the \section{} ? where \section{SOMETHING} ... SOMETHING appears properly within the above and below line.

Comment: what i realized is that the first \section{} of the text works fine, however, all subsequent \section{} fail to work properly as the text is not "placed" correctly.

Comment: nevermind about this sectioning placement.  I calibrated the `\sectionrule` in the preamble and it works fine. It's obscure though and I dont think I really wanna know why it works fine. I'll be experimenting with this final version ... and keep you posted on whether there are new problem. Many many thanks though for figuring out the \centering problem. I am blind, it appears.